# How to change the image icon of line share plugin

Tags: javascript, css

I have embedded this plugin from line.

```
 <div class="line-it-button" data-lang="en" data-type="share-f" data- 
  url="www.example.com" style="display: none;"></div><script 
  src="https://d.line-scdn.net/r/web/social- 
  plugin/js/thirdparty/loader.min.js" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```

This appears the line image icon. I want to change it according to my own custom image saved on my local folder but it didn't take effect since it is a frame.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

If that service does not offer any possibility to change this in either any type of account settings, or via an additional parameter - then you are basically out of luck.

The Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with the content of an iframe that was loaded from a different domain via your own scripting, and you can not apply CSS across frame borders either.

---

You *could* try an position your own icon on top of the iframe, and use `pointer-events: none` to let any clicks pass right through it. But depending on the type of service and whether they have any “security” measures implemented, that might get flagged as a “click jacking” attempt - and if not by them, then maybe by certain browsers or extensions. I would not really recommend it. Even if it might work now, that could change at some point.